# Printing out expression code and value

Tags: c#, expression

Is it possible to implement printing out expression code and value given an expression code as string?

```
class MyClass
{
    // Expected output 
    // 2 + 2 = 4
    // v = 3
    // Field = 5
    // OtherClass.GetInfo() = Hello
    // new OtherClass().OtherField = 22
    // 
    void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ExpressionPrintString("2 + 2")); 
        int v = 3;
        Console.WriteLine(ExpressionPrintString("v")); 
        Console.WriteLine(ExpressionPrintString("Field")); 
        Console.WriteLine(ExpressionPrintString("OtherClass.GetInfo()")); 
        Console.WriteLine(ExpressionPrintString("new OtherClass().OtherField")); 
    }
    int Field = 5;
}

class OtherClass
{
    public static sting GetInfo() { return "Hello"; }
    public int OtherField = 22;
}
```

I am aware of that [`Expression<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows to do it for Lambda expressions, like this:

```
    // Usage: ExpressionPrintString(() => 2 + 2) // returns "2 + 2 = 4"
    static string ExpressionPrintString(Expression<Func<object>> expr, string delimiter = " = ")
    {
        return expr.ToString().Replace("() => ","") 
               + delimiter 
               + expr.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
    }
```

but its output is sometimes not pretty, because it returns the internal representation of the expression. For example

```
    protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
    {
        // In this context
        // The following call: 
        string s = ExpressionPrintString(() => Context.Items["UrlRewrite:OriginalUrl"]);
        // returned:
        // value(ASP.default_aspx).Context.Items.get_Item("UrlRewrite:OriginalUrl") = http://localhost:8011/Companies
        // The expected output would be 
        // Context.Items["UrlRewrite:OriginalUrl"] = http://localhost:8011/Companies
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more precise on the current output and the expected output?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, Thank you for your comment, I updated the question, I hope now the expected output is clear.

Comment: Is your problem in the `get_Item` or the `value(ASP.default_aspx)`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, yes, updated once more

Comment: So your problem is in both?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, my problem is both `get_item` and `value(ASP.default_aspx)`